# How to compare the equality of classes in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a class like as follows.

```
export const MIN_EXPERIENCE = 0;
export const MAX_EXPERIENCE = 100;

export class Character {
  constructor(experience=0) {
    this._experience = experience;
  }
}
```

I want to compare two Characters and see which is greater, and this will be defined by who has more experience.

```
const lowLevelCharacter = new Character(MIN_EXPERIENCE);
const highLevelCharacter = new Character(MAX_EXPERIENCE);

console.log(lowLevelCharacter < highLevelCharacter); // should return `true`.
```

In a language like python, this might be implemented via the usage of `__eq__`, `__gt__`, or `__lt__` "dunder" methods. However, I don't find this same concept included within the documentation for es6 and es7.

How should this be implemented in JavaScript?

Comment: no such thing in the pipe for javascript, you have to implenent a lessThen() method

Answer (score 2):

Write your own comparator since you have a specific comparison in mind.

Write a prototype method on Character:

```
Character.prototype.higherLevelThan = function(character) {
  return this._experience > character._experience
}
```

Use:

```
highLevelChar.greaterLevelThan(lowLevelChar) // true
lowLevelChar.greaterLevelThan(highLevelChar) // false
```